# add gt table image to word doc with shiny and officer package

Tags: r, shiny, officer, gt

I am writing a shiny app which:

- creates a gt table
- saves the gt table as an image (temporary file)
- passes that image into a word doc using {officer} package

I am having difficulty with the image creation .... any help appreciated... here is my reprex

```
library(shiny)
library(gt)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
      
      
      downloadButton("report", "Generate Report")
      
      
)



server <- function(input, output, session) {
      
      
      my_table <- render_gt(
                
                mtcars[1:5,1:5] %>%
                          gt()
      )
      
      my_image <-reactive({
                
                outfile <- tempfile(fileext='.png')
                
                gtsave(my_table, outfile, width = 400, height = 300)
                
                
                
      })
      
      
      
      output$report <- downloadHandler(
                
                filename = function() {
                          "download.docx"
                },
                
                content = function(file) {
                          
                          
                          print(read_docx() %>%
                                          body_add_img(my_image()),
                                target = file)
                          
                          
                },
                contentType = "docx"
                
                
      )
      
      
      
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code:

1. You use `render_gt` instead of `reactive`.
2. Your `reactive` my_image does not return the name of the temporary file which is needed to add it to the docx. Additionally, as `my_table` is or should be a `reactive` use `my_table()`
3. In `gtsave` use `vwidth` and `vheight`. See `?webshot::webshot`.
4. In `officer::body_add_img` you have to set a `width` and `height` in **inches**.

Reproducible code:

```
library(shiny)
library(gt)
library(dplyr)
library(officer)

ui <- fluidPage(
  downloadButton("report", "Generate Report")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  my_table <- reactive({
    mtcars[1:5, 1:5] %>%
      gt()  
  })
  
  my_image <- reactive({
    outfile <- tempfile(fileext = ".png")
    gtsave(my_table(), outfile, vwidth = 400, vheight = 300)
    outfile
  })

  output$report <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      "download.docx"
    },
    content = function(file) {
      read_docx() %>%
        body_add_img(my_image(), width = 4, height = 3) %>%
        print(target = file)
    },
    contentType = "docx"
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: works great, learned a lot